# How to make nginx ingress strip -blue/-green suffixes from host names of any incoming requests before routing them to namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a k8s cluster with many services accessible through nginx ingress. Suppose `https://xyz.acme.com` is one of the many urls landing into one of the services. Again, passing through the ingress.

Now I would like to implement a transparent rewrite of the urls **BEFORE** they are matched to the services running in different namespaces. Specifically, I want to drop a well known suffix (`-blue`) from the host name, if it is present. So, `https://xyz-blue.acme.com` should be routed to the same service as `https://xyz.acme.com`.

However, I do not want to require the different teams implementing these services to specify the "blue" host names in their ingress specs. I want it to be completely transparent and automated.

Is there a way to do it?

P.S.
We use AKS 1.25 with Nginx ingress installed through their helm chart.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My most popular question is not a pure programming question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-work and yet no one argues it is very valuable to many developers. Do not make this forum more irrelevant than it may already be due to ChatGPT.

Comment: You are welcome to discuss this on meta.

Comment: The standard Nginx Ingress controller does not support hostname rewriting out of the box. To implement this feature, you need to create a custom Ingress controller that overrides the default Ingress controller behaviour. You can try adding nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation to the ingress resource that you want to modify. The purpose of "ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet" is to add some custom Nginx configuration which is not added by the ingress controller by default or using other annotations as per Nginx documentation.

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/ and https://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html